# Application is not deployed in destination cluster when using ApplicationSet and Application kind

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, argocd

I have ArgoCD running in one of my clusters (for the sake of this post lets name it prod) and I want to deploy applications on different cluster (staging) but it is not working. What I want to achieve is to deploy Application CRD on my prod cluster and deploy prometheus resources on my staging cluster. Within Argocd UI I can see error suggesting that no resource found.

prod EKS version: 2.21
staging EKS version: 2.24
ArgoCD version: 2.3.3

I'm using ApplicationSet to manage my applications as follows:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: myapplicationset 
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - git:
      repoURL: myrepo
      revision: main
      directories:
      - path: argocd/applications/*
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{path.basenameNormalized}}'
      namespace: argocd
    spec:
      project: "myproject"
      source:
        repoURL: myrepoURL
        targetRevision: main
        path: '{{path}}'
      destination:
        name: staging
        namespace: '{{path.basenameNormalized}}'
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true
        syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true
```

Within my Git repo I have following Application definition to deploy prometheus (it may be any app) under argocd/applications/prometheus/prometheus.yaml

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  project: myproject
  source:
    chart: prometheus
    repoURL: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
    targetRevision: 14.9.2
    helm:
      releaseName: prometheus
  destination:
    name: staging
    namespace: prometheus
```

After I replace prometheus.yaml with following Chart.yaml everything works fine and application is progressing as expected.

```
apiVersion: v2
name: prometheus

type: application
version: 14.9.2
appVersion: "14.9.2"

dependencies:
  - name: prometheus
    version: 14.9.2
    repository: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
```

In argocd/applications/ I have different directories which contain both Chart.yaml and native kubernetes manifests and all of them work as expected.

Is there something I'm missing here? I went through [ArgoCD docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/) but haven't found much details on how one can deploy applications on different cluster while using ApllicationSet and Application manifest without having ArgoCD CRDs on both clusters.

Comment: Check applicationset logs out with a command like this: `kubetail argocd-applicationset-controller- -s 1000s` and look for errors